# Access script of a published web app

Tags: web-applications, google-apps-script

Hi I found a google web app that shows the exchange rates of different currencies, I would like to access the original code to see how it was made. Is there a way to do this or am I blocked? I hope I am not missing something obvious.

Here is the app in question https://script.google.com/a/macros/essilor.com.sg/s/AKfycbxImXs3GS_G1Cdiqefg1pu_BQTwMWNQ5iwbAuy1eEer5ePkG9kt/exec

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access web based application unless the owner deploy it as "Who has access to the app: Anyone / Anyone, even anonymous"

In order to fetch exchange rates you can use the below.

```
 var sheetDatabase = SpreadsheetApp.openById("<<Spreadsheet ID>>").getSheetByName("<<sheet Name>>");
 sheetDatabase.getRange(2, 1).setFormula('=GOOGLEFINANCE("CURRENCY:EURUSD")');
```

[Google Documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093281?visit_id=1-636370809605600262-694433847&hl=en-GB&rd=1)